# Python 2+3 compatible code: Should I avoid six?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, version-control, six

This guide, [Writing code that runs under both Python2 and 3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingToPy3k/BilingualQuickRef), states that

> Use the third party six module sparingly (i.e. only if necessary). One good use case is the reraise() method.

Why is this? I thought the whole point of `six` was to make Python 2+3 compatible code easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the point is to try and avoid 2/3 specific constructs where possible, and only employ things like `six` when you have no other native option - as it adds complexity and additional fault points to the code. Since `six` is faking some stuff to bridge the gap, you may find it doesn't always work exactly as intended.